# GKE Vertical expansion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Our team have a GKE cluster that use n1-standard-2 machine(2CPU), I read GCP's white paper and it mention Cluster Autoscaler, but we run mongoDB cluster in GKE. It is only primary node can provide service so it is no use add new node. Has any method modify machine kind?

Comment: Google's autoscaling support horizontal scaling (adding instances). It does not support vertical scaling (changing instance size).

Comment: it's on the beta surface --enable-vertical-pod-autoscaling, just keep in mind that's a beta surface.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the size once made, instead, create a new node pool with the correctly sized machine type and [migrate your workloads over to the new node pool](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/migrating-node-pool)